# Creating a new cocoapods pod

Tags: operating-system, cocoapods

I'm trying to create my first `pod`, and, as per the recommendation on the website, am doing so at the command line with `pod lib create <mylib>`. The trouble is `lib create` assumes I want to create an `iOS` library, when in fact I'm developing for `OS X`. I've `grep`'ed my way through the cocoapod files on my computer looking for the template on which the generated project is based, but have come up empty-handed. Does anyone know how I might fiddle with these settings, wherever they are, to get the configuration I'm after?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have your library created and just want to create a sample `podspec` you should use:

```
pod spec create
```

Instead. You can also pass this a URL to set that as the source automatically. See

```
pod spec create --help
```

For more info.